# Running Discord.js bot on Heroku with 2 Dynos is firing 2 events. 1 for each websocket connection

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, bots, discord.js

I'm running a Discord bot on Heroku with 2 dynos, each of which is opening a websocket connection, so for every event that's sent to the connection, my bot is reacting twice. Is there an easy way to deal with this short of adding a queue that validates uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from someone in the Discord.js discord server.

**Two dynos = two bots. Unless you're sharding properly across multiple dynos, all you're doing is running the same code on the same guilds twice**